# accesing WCF service through localhos works but through my public ip it doesnt

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-hosting, wcf-http

I have a self hosted WCF project, I accomplished to get it work when i enter:

> http://`localhost`:8000/Service/Method

but when i try to replace `localhost` with my public ip and access the service through a different computer it doesn't work.

I opened ports in my router and still doesnt work

any ideas?

Comment: More information is needed. Can you post serviceModel section of your app.config? Also, what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What exactly does not work?

Comment: Have you checked your firewall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the public IP configured directly on the computer which you host the service or is it the public IP of the router? If it is the second case, have you added a rule on your router to direct incoming traffic on port 8000 to be directed to the hosting computers port 8000 using port forwarding. And also you should have the firewall on hosting computer exempting port 8000 as pointed out by @Milan